# StepMonitor variable replacement depends on presence of constraint in FindMinimum

Tags: mathematical-optimization

Contrast the results of `StepMonitor` between the two calls to `FindMinimum`, which differ only in that the second contains a constraint on the argument to the objective function.

```
ClearAll[f, wrap, x];
f[x_] := (x)^2;
wrap = {x};
FindMinimum[{f[Sequence @@ wrap]}, x, StepMonitor :> Print["step to ", wrap]]
FindMinimum[{f[Sequence @@ wrap], x > 1}, x, StepMonitor :> Print["step to ", wrap]]

(*
step to {0.}
{0.,{x->0.}}
step to {x}
step to {x}
step to {x}
step to {x}
step to {x}
step to {x}
{1.,{x->1.}}
*)
```

The second version prints out `{x}` instead of the current guess of `x`. I need to be able to print out the current guess of the argument at each step without abandoning the constraint.

You might be wondering why I use `wrap` at all. The answer is that this is a minimal not working example of an issue I ran into for which the objective function is a function of several arguments, some of which are scalars with constraints, and some of which are variable length lists without constraints. I need to minimize the function over all of the arguments, and I can't hard code the arguments of the variable length lists into `StepMonitor`.

How could I alter my code so that `StepMonitor` will print out the current value of the arguments over which `FindMinimum` is searching without hard coding the variable names?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`With`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/With) to inject the value of `wrap` into your code (I also used `f @@ wrap` instead of your `f[Sequence @@ wrap]`):

```
f[x_] := x^2
With[{wrap = {x}},
    FindMinimum[{f@@wrap}, x, StepMonitor:>Print["step to ", wrap]]
]
```

> step to {0.}
>
> {0., {x -> 0.}}

compared to:

```
With[{wrap = {x}},
    FindMinimum[{f@@wrap, x>1}, x, StepMonitor:>Print["step to ", wrap]]
]
```

> step to {2.}
>
> step to {1.01}
>
> step to {1.00986}
>
> step to {1.00017}
>
> step to {1.}
>
> step to {1.}
>
> {1., {x -> 1.}}

Comment: Thank you. That worked in my more complicated setting as well.